# Express.js page refreshing prints content twice and twice

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am getting the content twice and twice for every each refresh. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

**names.js**

names.js reading a file

```
var names = {
    getNames: function(file) {
        var data = fs.readFileSync(file).toString().split("\n");

        for (i in data) {
            var line = data[i].replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim().split(" ");
            names.push(line[0])
       }
       return names;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    incr: names
}
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {names: incr.getNames(file)});
    console.log(req.url);   
    res.end();
}
```

**index.ejs**

```
<% for (i in names) { %>
<tr>
  <td><%= names[i] %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: what is the output of incr.getNames(file) ?

Comment: list of names of print in table

Comment: it seems fine. yes, you can use for(i in names). just give a try this once for(var i=0; i < names.length; i++) or provide more data to the question.

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't working. Actually array data is getting from other js file like names.js > app.js > index.ejs

Comment: Could you check the code again please. I updated it.